# Suddenly cannot load AdMob ads?

Tags: android, admob

My app was loading rewarded video ads without a problem. But, yesterday I started receiving the error code 3 on my device when attempting to load an ad. I did not change my app's code at all! Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

    System.out.println("error code " + errorCode); // error code 3
}
```

Things I tried:

- Upgraded all Google Play services API to 11.0.4 (latest) in `build.gradle`.
- Checked my AdMob page for any notifications.
- Checked my AD_UNIT_ID and APP_ID to make sure they're correct.
- Switched Wi-Fi networks (even tried with 4G).

Comment: try with a different AD_UNIT_ID ?

Comment: @AmodGokhale I tried a different AD_UNIT_ID but I get the same result...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL), code 3 means:

> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

There's probably no problem with your code. Just AdMob not having any ads to display at that time.

Comment: Thanks, but my app is failing to load ads for a **day** now. Maybe something else is wrong?